# No appropriate default constructor available templates

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I have a problem when i created an template object, i have a constructor but the program said that doesn't exists a correct constructor.
What is wrong?

Error c2512 ... no appropriate default constructor available appear in VS 2015

```
template <class T>
class CNODO_D
{private:
    T element;
    CNODO_D<T>* next;
    CNODO_D<T>* back;

public:
    CNODO_D(T e)
    {
        element = e;
        next = nullptr;
        back = nullptr;
    }
}

template <class T>
class CLista_S
{
private:
    CNODO<T>* begin;
    int _size;

public:CLista_S()
    {
        begin = nullptr;
        _size = 0;
    }
        void push_back(T e)
    {
        _size++;
        if (begin == nullptr)
        {
            CNODO_D<T>* n = new CNODO_D<T>(e);
            begin = n;
        }
        else
            //some other code
    }
}
    class CVida
{
private:
int vidas,x,y,ancho,alto;
int pos_inicial;
public:
CVida(int px, int py, int vid)
{
x = px;
y = py;
pos_inicial = px;
vidas = vid;
alto = 47;
ancho = 48;
}
    CLista_D<CVida>* lista_vidas= new CLista_D<CVida>();
lista_vidas->push_back(CVida, 12, 6, 9));
```

Comment: You code doesn't even mention `CVida`. How can we possibly know whether it has an appropriate constructor?

Comment: Please try to make a [mcve]. Include the full error message.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re using `CVida` as a value in the last line of your example. Perhaps you meant `lista_vidas->push_back(CVida{12, 6, 9})`? That’s not the real problem though.

The problem is that `CVida` [doesn’t have a default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-declared_default_constructor) but you’re calling the `CVida`default constructor in the `CNODO_D<CVida>` constructor. You should be using a [member init list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

```
template <class T>
class CNODO_D
{private:
    T element;
    CNODO_D<T>* next;
    CNODO_D<T>* back;

public:
    CNODO_D(T e)
        : element(e), next(), back() {}
}
```